# Openstack: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to install `Openstack` on `Ubuntu-18.04 LTS` using `devstack` and `./stack.sh` fails with below error.

```
Collecting setuptools!=24.0.0,!=34.0.0,!=34.0.1,!=34.0.2,!=34.0.3,!=34.1.0,!=34.1.1,!=34.2.0,!=34.3.0,!=34.3.1,!=34.3.2,!=36.2.0,<58.0.0
  Using cached setuptools-57.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for setuptools: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools-59.6.0.dist-info/METADATA'
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 59.6.0
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools-59.6.0.dist-info/RECORD'

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
++./stack.sh:main:766                       err_trap
++./stack.sh:err_trap:544                   local r=1
++./stack.sh:err_trap:545                   set +o xtrace
stack.sh failed
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-01-02-070122.txt for details
```

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/stack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (21.3.1)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for setuptools: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools-59.6.0.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Tried to `pip install setuptools` and `pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps setuptools==59.6.0` but couldn't help.

What I'm missing to complete the installation?

Comment: Have you found some solutions/workarounds in the mean while?

Comment: Yes the above issue solved, i have completed removed the openstak by running `unstack.sh` and `clean.sh`

Answer (score -1):

The following example shows the command for installing the OpenStack client with  `pip`, which supports multiple services.

```
 pip install python-openstackclient
```

The following individual clients are deprecated in favor of a common client. Instead of installing and learning all these clients, we recommend installing and using the OpenStack client. You may need to install an individual project’s client because coverage is not yet sufficient in the OpenStack client. If you need to install an individual client’s project, replace the  `PROJECT`  name in this  `pip  install`  command using the list below.

```
 pip install python-PROJECTclient
```

Please find more information on [here](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/user-guide/common/cli-install-openstack-command-line-clients.html) about installing the OpenStack on Ubuntu or other OS.

Comment: You are unfortunately talking about something completely different than what was being asked in the question.